# Node.js - Pushing to an array inline

Tags: javascript, node.js

Why are these two values different?

```
var sliced = [1,2].slice(1);
sliced.push(3);
console.log(sliced);


var sliced = [1,2].slice(1).push(3);
console.log(sliced);
```

perhaps this can shed light onto why this doesn't work:

```
var result = process.argv.slice(1).push('xyz');
```

but this does:

```
var result = process.argv.slice(1).concat('xyz');
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.push` returns the new length of the array that the value was pushed to, not the array it was pushing to.

Comment: `.push` only returns the length of the array and since an array is 0-based indexed the last index would always be length - 1.

Answer (score 2):

.push method return the length of array it was pushed to. For details take a look [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push)

.push returns as per MDN

> The new length property of the object upon which the method was
>   called.

So even if you take 5, 6 and 7 as array element it will return length of array

```
var sliced = ([5,6,7].slice(1)).push(3);
console.log(sliced);
```

Output is 3